# Problema de enrutamiento de un modulo hijo

Tags: angularjs

Tengo un problema con el routing que no consigo arreglar.

Trato de acceder a la ruta /admin/login y me dirige al raiz con página en blanco y el siguiente error en la consola:

> ```
> ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
> Error
>     at Error.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfil……}
> ```

Las demás rutas si que funcionan

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'},
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

**admin.routing.module.ts**

```
const AdminRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: AdminLoginComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: AdminHomeComponent },
    { path: '', component: AdminComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(AdminRoutes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

Comment: Hola Apicito, bienvenido. Mientras te contestan, recuerda pasar por el [tour] y [ask] para saber más del funcionamiento del sitio. Un saludo !

Answer (score 0):

Me autorespondo para decir que el problema estaba en el propio componente de login, aun que no he conseguido averiguar cual era, no en routing.
He procedido a eliminar el componente y volver a crearlo y ya todo funciona.
Saludos.